# How to show multiple dialog polyfill?

Tags: javascript, dialog, modal-dialog

I have script to open dialog polyfill :

```
window.modalDialog = function (url, arg, opt) {
        url = url || ''; //URL of a dialog
        arg = arg || null; //arguments to a dialog
        opt = opt || 'dialogWidth:300px;dialogHeight:200px'; //options: dialogTop;dialogLeft;dialogWidth;dialogHeight or CSS styles

        var caller = modalDialog.caller.toString();
        var dialog = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('dialog'));
        var splitter = opt.split(",");
        dialog.setAttribute('style', splitter[0].replace(/dialog/gi, ''));
        dialog.innerHTML = '<a href="#" id="dialog-close">&times;</a><iframe id="dialog-body" src="' + url + '" style="border: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></iframe>';
        document.getElementById('dialog-body').contentWindow.dialogArguments = arg;
        document.getElementById('dialog-close').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            dialog.close();
        });
        dialog = document.querySelector('dialog');
        dialogPolyfill.registerDialog(dialog);

        function addListeners() {
            document.querySelector('dialog').addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);
            window.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp, false);
        }

        function mouseUp()
        {
            window.removeEventListener('mousemove', divMove, true);
        }

        function mouseDown(e) {
            window.addEventListener('mousemove', divMove, true);
        }

        function divMove(e) {
            var div = document.querySelector('dialog');
            div.style.position = 'absolute';
            div.style.top = e.clientY + 'px';
            div.style.left = e.clientX + 'px';
        }

        addListeners();
        dialog.showModal();
        dialog.addEventListener('close', function () {
            var returnValue = document.getElementById('dialog-body').contentWindow.returnValue;
            document.body.removeChild(dialog);
            nextStmts[0] = nextStmts[0].replace(/(window\.)?modalDialog\(.*\)/g, JSON.stringify(returnValue));
            eval('{\n' + nextStmts.join('\n'));
        });
        throw 'Execution stopped until modalDialog is closed';
    };
```

when I call this script, dialog-body got replaced with new url instead create new dialog. How can i create multiple dialog?

**EDIT**

My biggest problem is that my dialogs has the same parent (caller), so in dialog polyfill js library, there's script to check if there are dialogs or not in parent document, if yes, then throw warning `Failed to execute showModal on dialog: The element is already open, and therefore cannot be opened modally.`

**EDIT**

I have created the jsfiddle, but i dont know how to call external source website from jsfiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/godofrayer/gvLpLjkq/

Comment: does [this](https://github.com/niutech/showModalDialog/blob/gh-pages/showModalDialog.js) help?

Comment: i am using that code from him, and still cannot create multiple dialog.

Comment: oh yeah, you are using part of that code

Comment: can you provide fiddle showing current state?

Comment: **1)** I was able to open 2 different modals with [showModalDialog](https://github.com/niutech/showModalDialog/blob/gh-pages/showModalDialog.js) by calling `spawn` function twice; **2)** they were a bit broken (won't closing), but can be easily fixed; **3)** if you provide runnable demo with your own setup which is different from `spawn` stuff (on jsfiddle, plunker or whatever), I'm sure we'll have a good chance to solve your issue too.

Comment: The problem is `document.getElementById`. This assumes there to be only one element by that id; if there are two, it'll always fetch the first one. You can get around this by instead using `dialog.querySelector( "#id" )` (I would instead advise you to use classes, however, as duplicate IDs are against spec). [Here's a recursive fiddle example.](https://jsfiddle.net/7bk088o3/3/)

Answer (score 1):

I modified your example a little bit and now you can open multiple dialogs. 
The problem was the `getElementById`. An id has to be unique in a document. So I have organized the dialogs in an array, and the ID-elements now contain the index of the array at the the end of the id: `id="dialog-close'+dlgIndex+'"`.

My modification is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gvLpLjkq/1/)

Here you can see the main changes:

```
var dlgs = [];
    window.showModalDialog = window.showModalDialog || function(url, arg, opt) {
        url = url || ''; //URL of a dialog
        arg = arg || null; //arguments to a dialog
        opt = opt || 'dialogWidth:300px;dialogHeight:200px'; //options: dialogTop;dialogLeft;dialogWidth;dialogHeight or CSS styles        
        var caller = showModalDialog.caller.toString();

        var dialog = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('dialog'));
        // Adds the Dialog to an Array of Dialogs
        var dlgIndex = dlgs.length;
        dlgs[dlgIndex] = dialog;
        dialog.setAttribute('style', opt.replace(/dialog/gi, ''));
        dialog.innerHTML = '<a href="#" id="dialog-close'+dlgIndex+'" style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 4px; font-size: 20px; color: #000; text-decoration: none; outline: none;">&times;</a><iframe id="dialog-body'+dlgIndex+'" src="' + url + '" style="border: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></iframe>';
        document.getElementById('dialog-body'+dlgIndex).contentWindow.dialogArguments = arg;
        document.getElementById('dialog-close'+dlgIndex).addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            dialog.close();
        });
        dialog.showModal();
        //if using yield
        if(caller.indexOf('yield') >= 0) {
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                dialog.addEventListener('close', function() {
                    var returnValue = document.getElementById('dialog-body'+dlgIndex).contentWindow.returnValue;
                    document.body.removeChild(dialog);
                    resolve(returnValue);
                });
            });
        }
        //if using eval
        var isNext = false;
        var nextStmts = caller.split('\n').filter(function(stmt) {
            if(isNext || stmt.indexOf('showModalDialog(') >= 0)
                return isNext = true;
            return false;
        });
        dialog.addEventListener('close', function() {
            var returnValue = document.getElementById('dialog-body'+dlgIndex).contentWindow.returnValue;
            document.body.removeChild(dialog);
            nextStmts[0] = nextStmts[0].replace(/(window\.)?showModalDialog\(.*\)/g, JSON.stringify(returnValue));
            eval('{\n' + nextStmts.join('\n'));
        });
        //throw 'Execution stopped until showModalDialog is closed';
    };
})();

var showDialog = function() {
    window.showModalDialog("https://heise.de/");
  console.log("ShowSecond!!!")
  window.showModalDialog("https://www.heise.de/newsticker/meldung/Einstweilige-Verfuegung-Vodafone-muss-Kinox-to-sperren-3966023.html");
};
```

Hope this helps.